# Element misplaced in Chrome after responsive adjustment

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have tried to add some simple responsiveness on a [website](http://myhymnal.net) and there's something strange going on in Chrome which I'm unable to figure out how to fix.

The problem is with the search bar in the upper right corner which should be placed in the middle of the bar like in the left image.

If I decrease the width of the browser until the search bar jumps below the menu (which works great btw), and then resize it back out, the search bar ends up like on the right.

[image: Good] [image: Bad]

If I refresh the page it jumps back to where it should be. In FireFox and IE it works as I expected. What am I missing here?

---

**LESS source**

- [Regular styles for search bar](https://github.com/Svish/myhymnal/blob/master/less/general.less#L205)
- [Responsiveness](https://github.com/Svish/myhymnal/blob/master/less/responsiveness.less#L41)

Answer (score 1):

I change this line with `display: inline-block;` to `display: inline-table;`:

```
#header h1, #header nav, #header form, #header img, #header ul, #header li, #header input {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    display: inline-table; /* This */ 
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

and it works in FF and Chrome

**UPDATE**

For a better solution or "not so ugly":

I wrapped the `<form>` into a `<div>` tag, see here: [**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/itoFIMIq/3/)

Here a part of the CSS:

```
/* REMOVE HERE THE FLOAT RIGHT */
#header #search { margin-top:-3px; }    

#header #search input{width:200px;padding:3px 7px;font-size:90%;border-radius:3px;}

/* SET HERE THE FLOAT RIGHT AND DISPLAY INLINE */
#searchForm { float: right; display: inline;}

h1:first-child,article:first-child{margin-top:0;}

@media only screen and (max-width: 850px){

  #header nav ul{margin-top:.5em;display:block;}
  #header h1,#header ul li{margin-right:0;}      
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 550px){

  #header{text-align:center;}
  #header #search{margin-top:.5em;display:block;float:none;}
  #header #search input{width:95%;}

  /* SET HERE THE FLOAT NONE */
  #searchForm{float: none;}
}
```

HTML:

```
<!-- WRAP THE FORM INTO A DIV-->

    <div id="searchForm">
        <form id="search" role="search" action="search" method="get">
            <input type="search" name="term" placeholder="Song title or number..." tabindex="1">
        </form>
    </div>
```

Tested in FF and Chrome, I hope this is help you more.

Comment: That does seem to work. I'd sure like to know why it was broken, though.

Comment: my english is not the best for good explain, I am more practical than theoretical developer... but here is maybe a good info for the different between: `display: inline-block;` and `display: inline-table;`

Comment: I understand the difference. What I don't know is why Chrome renders the layout one way before resize and a different way after.

Comment: Yeah, what @isherwood said. Also I gotta say it feels a bit ugly to use a display mode related to table for this...

Comment: ... so, basically what you're saying is to style a wrapping `div` rather than a standalone `form`?

Comment: Yes... in your case (CSS-stylesheet), I think is the "_best_" option/solution.

Comment: This just happened to me. Setting the container to display:inline-table is the only thing that worked. Goddamn Chrome. Better browser my a**.